# How to keep video controls from overlapping

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Given the following jQuery to control placement of video controls, when the player is larger and/or fullscreen, the time played/time-total and sound/fullscreen controls overlap. How can I keep these from doing so?

```
$('document').ready(function () {
// resize on dom ready
resizePlayer();

// add window resize binding
$(window).resize(resizePlayer);
});

function resizePlayer() {
    var newWidth = $('.timeline').outerHeight() * 0.25;

    var containerSize = $('.timeline').width();
    var textPercentage = 0.17391; /* 40/230 */
    var textRatio = containerSize * textPercentage;
    var textEms = textRatio / 144;

    $('.play, .pause, .mute, .fullscreen').width(newWidth);
    $('.time-played, .time-total').css('fontSize', textEms+"em");
}
```

Here is a fiddle of the current code: http://jsfiddle.net/mattography/zq2vzkk5/8/

It can be seen in action here: http://jsfiddle.net/mattography/zq2vzkk5/8/show

Comment: It is because of the `fontSize` at the last line of `resizePlayer()`. Either comment it or decrease `textEms`

Comment: I found it was a simple adjustment to the css for the margin of the pause button. What really needs work, is the padding/size of the font that changes(but should just stay the same, relative to the buttons) when the screen is shrunk down. Any thoughts?